# One way association with array of reference _id in sails js

Tags: sails.js, waterline, sails-mongo

I'm trying to use one way association because I need only to have reference from 1 model to other model but not vice versa.

Model Arts:

```
module.exports = {
 attributes: {
  fileName: {type: 'string', required: true},
  softwareUsed: {
   model: 'Softwares'
  }
 }
}
```

---

Model Softwares:

```
module.exports = {
 attributes: {
  name: {type: 'string', required: true}
 }
}
```

This is my api:

```
http://localhost:1337/api/v1/arts/create
```

if this is my request body, it works fine:

```
request body:
{
    "fileName": "booking.jpeg",
    "softwareUsed": "5e70309cbf12b61299d6c528",
}
```

but i want to store array of softwareUsed, so i tried:

```
request body:
{
    "fileName": "booking.jpeg",
    "softwareUsed": ["5e70309cbf12b61299d6c528", "5e70309cbf12b61299d6c529"],
}
```

but i got an error with that:

```
error: OperationalError [UsageError]: Invalid new record.
Details:
  Could not use specified `softwareUsed`.  Expecting an id representing the associated record, or `null` to indicate there will be no associated record.  But the specified value is not a valid `softwareUsed`.  Instead of a string (the expected pk type), the provided value is: [ '5e70309cbf12b61299d6c528', '5e70309cbf12b61299d6c529' ]
```

I also tried to make it array in model:

```
softwareUsed: [{
       model: 'Softwares'
      }]
```

but still don't work.

Is there a way to that in one way association or I need to use other association, but how can I achieve that?
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to label the `softwareUsed` attribute with a `collection`, not a `model`:

```
module.exports = {
 attributes: {
  fileName: {type: 'string', required: true},
  softwareUsed: {
   collection: 'Softwares'
  }
 }
}
```

All the documentation on one-to-many in the sails docs involves two-way associations and adding a `via` attribute, but I think this way works for a one-way association.

Of course, your first api call may now longer work: you may need to wrap the single software id in an array.

Comment: You mean like this? "softwareUsed": [["5e70309cbf12b61299d6c528"], ["5e70309cbf12b61299d6c529"]],

Comment: Nope, either `softwareUsed: ["5e70309cbf12b61299d6c528"]` or `softwareUsed: ["5e70309cbf12b61299d6c528", "5e70309cbf12b61299d6c529"]`.

Comment: as i said in my post this don't work: softwareUsed: ["5e70309cbf12b61299d6c528", "5e70309cbf12b61299d6c529"]

Comment: That won't cause error, but the softwareUsed will not be stored in database. Only other fields.

Comment: @noyruto88 did you try this format after updating your model to use `collection` instead of `model` in it's connected attribute?